# Good tutorial for coding up estimator functions in R

Tags: r, instrumental-variables

I want to code up [Lewbel's "special regressor"](https://www2.bc.edu/arthur-lewbel/simplenew14.pdf) estimator in R, and I'd like to make it into something that others can use.  I can write simple functions, but I don't fully understand the guts of even simple estimators like `lm`.  (I understand them statistically, but there are lots of things that are just programming, like `match.dots` and `environment` and specifying `attributes` and such.)

Is there a good, applied introduction somewhere?  Ideally something that dissects a well-known function, explaining the steps and tools used?

(I recognize that this question would be better-suited to stackoverflow, but there is an explicit prohibition on asking about tutorials on that site, I'm not sure what terms to plug into google, and there are specific programming considerations when applied to statistical estimators.)

Comment: I would recommend to look at the source code of packages that have implemented similar estimators. For example, in our `AER` package there is the `ivreg()` function. Its formula processing for response, regressors, and instruments is based on the `Formula` package (whose vignette also has a very simple IV example). The `betareg` package and its first vignette might be useful for maximum likelihood estimation with multiple parts. And the `plm` package for panel data...

Answer (score 1):

This [tutorial](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Leisch-CreatingPackages.pdf) on creating packages may be of help. It introduces R programming, and includes a class and method example using linear regression. This [one](http://hilaryparker.com/2014/04/29/writing-an-r-package-from-scratch/) should help through the details of building and sharing an R package.